# Sparql - Get linked Class data properties along with primary Class

Tags: sparql

In SPARQL - How can I get  object B's data property if that object B is linked to object A via some object property?  Like in my case, `Automobile` and `Registration` are two classes, and `automobile` has `hasRegistration` object property. `Registration` has data property `registration_number`. So I want to get `registration_number` value along with data properties of `Automobile`.

In SQL, we do this with `JOIN` on different tables but here I don't know how to mention two class objects as tables to join them. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just use [property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#pp-language)

Comment: SPARQL is also using joins on triple patterns. just write triple patterns for each class and then another triple patterns that links the variables via the given property.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any other Q&As on this topic? It's important to [follow site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions.

Comment: Worth noting that SQL `JOIN` is used in many DBMS, not just MySQL. Also that [SPARQL queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) have some similarities to SQL, but overall are very different. "Class objects" are not "tables" to be joined.

Comment: Thanks @ Ivo Velitchov and @ AKSW, I got your point and my issue is resolved. Thanks for correction @TallTed.